# How can I extract matching values, if checked, from three sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZT80xj66cU5DvxnDoVkmdZb8_-IkZyqnTPthqkYfchw/edit?usp=sharing) I'm trying to list or at least mark matching values from three sheets with the same statements.

If Person 1, 2 and 3 check the same statement it's supposed be listed in "Desired output".

I have tried FILTER, MATCH and IF but I'm not quite lucky with either or combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the statements are in the same order in all the sheets, like in the provided example, you can use:

```cpp
=BYROW({'Person 1'!A2:A11\'Person 2'!A2:A11\'Person 3'!A2:A11};LAMBDA(r;IF(AND(r);r)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if it's appropiate to ask but having 100+ statements is it possible to filter the checked ones in a shorter list?

Comment: try this out: `=FILTER({'Person 1'!A2:A11\'Person 2'!A2:A11\'Person 3'!A2:A11},BYROW({'Person 1'!A2:A11\'Person 2'!A2:A11\'Person 3'!A2:A11};LAMBDA(r;AND(r))))`